# REACTJS pass a variable into props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
galleryItems = () => {
    console.log("brands", this.state.brands)

    var obj = []

    var filteredData = this.state.brands.forEach((item) => {
        var lol = item.media.filter((item2) => item2.collection_name === "images")
        obj = [...obj, ...lol]

    })
    console.log("obj", obj)

    return obj.map((image, i) => (
        <div key={i}  className="card-img-top"><img src={image.url} onClick={this.props.carouselBrand()}/></div>
    ));
  };
```

I have filtered out this.state.brands
[image]

as you can see, it has media. I have filtered it and mapped all the media that has a collection_name === "images"

[image]

and on this line of code:
`<div key={i}  className="card-img-top"><img src={image.url} onClick={this.props.carouselBrand()}/></div>`
I want to pass the slug value of that image in the onClick function. But I don't know how because I have already filtered it. How can I get the slug of the brand?

Comment: Have you tried getting the value before you filter?

Comment: @Adam I don't know how to do that and match it to the appropriate image since the brands are also an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

decorate the objects you compose.

```
var filteredData = this.state.brands.forEach(({media, slug}) => {
  const lol = media.filter(item2 => item2.collection_name === "images").map(image => ({ slug, ...image }));
  obj.push.apply(obj, lol);
})
console.log("obj", obj)

return obj.map((image, i) => (
    <div key={i}  className="card-img-top"><img src={image.url} onClick={() => this.props.carouselBrand(image.slug)}/></div>
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either append `slug` to your new array, or keep a copy of the initial object with filtered `media`.

```
const obj = [].concat(...this.state.brands.map(item =>
               item.media.map(item2 => ({ slug: item.slug, ...item2 }) )
                  .filter(item2 => item2.collection_name === 'images'));
```